# Read the line within function block php

Tags: php

At first I read the file and if the line contains `function` keyword, I want to read the line within function block. My file structure is

```
function some_method2() {
    one;
}
function some_method3() {
    two;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$obj = new SplFileObject('filename','r+');
while(!$obj->eof()){
$curr_line = $obj->current();
if(strpos($curr_line,"function" )!==false){
$obj->next();
while(strpos($obj->current(),'}')!== true)
{
$body .= $obj->current();
$obj->next();
} 
}
else{
$obj->next();
}
}
```

Comment: I am using  while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets($readfile))) {  like that how to use next() ?

Comment: Please check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) to know more about the SplFileObject 
You can use `fgets()` to read line by line inside the loop . To know about `fgets` click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) .